# Change navbar color when background is white

Tags: javascript, css, mix-blend-mode

My page has sections with background images and others with white background. My nav text color is white. When the nav is over the image background, it is possible to see it. When it is over a white background section, it disappears.

[white nav over section with image background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTbW2.png)

I know of the `mix-blend-mode` CSS property. I have tried pretty much every possible value (cf. CSS Tricks `/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/`, since I apparently can't post more than two links...) for it. Only `exclusion` and `difference` produce a good result for white nav over white, but a bad result for white over image.

What I want, is that the nav stays always white, unless it is over a white background.

I have thought of a JS approach that binds a class to the nav when it detects that the background is white. This is possible since all of my white background sections have a `.light` class. This solution works fine, but it seems a bit heavy (demanding in resources) since it runs every time a scroll event is detected on the document element:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {

    var menu = $('#menu');

    current_scroll = $(this).scrollTop() + 40;

    // Placed here because some white sections may vary in height
    var light_sections = $('.section.light');

    var i, start, end;
    for (i = 0; i < light_sections.length; i++) {
        start = $(light_sections[i]).offset().top;
        end = start + $(light_sections[i]).outerHeight();

        if (start < current_scroll && current_scroll < end) {
            $(menu).addClass('dark');
            return true;
        }
    }

    $(menu).removeClass('dark');
});
```

I like the `mix-blend-mode` solution because it does not require much resources, but it doesn't work for my usage, plus I think it has cross browser support issues. I like my solution because it works, but could slow down the page IMHO. Could anyone suggest a simpler solution or tell me if blend mode could do the trick ?

Codepen with my working solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwXVKm

Comment: Can you include all of the relevant tags/code in order to reproduce the page all into a single runnable snippet?

Comment: your js solution looks good to me

Comment: I just edited my post to add a codepen example. My solution is correct and works fine, but I was wondering whether there is a less resource demanding CSS or JS based solution.